# "BUG IN FGRAPH.REPLACE OR A LISTENER" error reported when compile theano function

Tags: python, theano

I encountered an stranger error as below, when compile my theano function. I am using the version 0.7 of theano. I hope a quick work around is available. The function dump is [here](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1eQGsjIE).

```
<<!! BUG IN FGRAPH.REPLACE OR A LISTENER !!>> <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>  local_shape_to_shape_i
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: local_shape_to_shape_i
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1527, in process_node
fgraph.replace_all_validate(repl_pairs, reason=lopt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/toolbox.py", line 259, in replace_all_validate
fgraph.replace(r, new_r, reason=reason, verbose=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/fg.py", line 502, in replace
self.change_input(node, i, new_r, reason=reason)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/fg.py", line 442, in change_input
self.__import_r__([new_r], reason=reason)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/fg.py", line 257, in __import_r__
self.__import__(apply_node, reason=reason)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/fg.py", line 365, in __import__
assert node not in self.apply_nodes
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message appears when a bug in a Theano optimization causes an invalid graph modification.

If you ever see "Optimization failure due to: <something>", try the following:

1. Search the internet, and the [theano-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/theano-users) in particular, for the message including the specific <something> (in this case <something> is "local_shape_to_shape_i"). You may find a message indicating that the bug has already been identified. If it's been reported to the Theano developers then it may have already been fixed though you may need to update to the bleeding edge version of Theano direct from GitHub (i.e. pip install --upgrade may not be sufficient).
2. Even if you can't find any mention online, try updating to the bleeding edge version if that's possible for you. It may have already been fixed.
3. If the latest bleeding edge version still exhibits the bug then report it on the [theano-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/theano-users).
4. Ignore it. Optimization failures do not cause invalid computations. The only side effect (at least in theory) is that the computation may not be as efficient as it might otherwise be.